# Add hash to url and active correct section

Tags: jquery, tabs, jquery-ui-tabs

HTML:

```
<section id="horizontal_nav">
 <nav>
   <a class="product_name active" href="#"><p>vc-1</p></a>
   <a class="product_name" href="#"><p>vc-2</p></a>
   <a class="product_name" href="#"><p>vc-3</p></a>
 </nav>
</section>

<article class="product_info">
//content vc-1
</article>
<article class="product_info">
//content vc-2
</article>
<article class="product_info">
//content vc-3
</article>
```

JS to jump between articles:

```
$('.product_name').on('touchstart click', function(e) {
        $('.product_name').removeClass('active');
        $(this).toggleClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();

        $('.product_info').animate({left: +$(this).index() * -100+'vw'}, 500);
    });
```

I see a lot of examples regarding to the JQuery UI plugin. But in my opinion it is way to complicated. My question is, which line of code do I need to add the right hashtag to the url, so our customers directly can link to the right article-tag via the url as you can see in the HTML?

Kind regards,